# Creating a tiled table with images and data in R

Tags: r, flextable

I am attempting to generate a report based on a series of images with their descriptions. The paths to the images and the descriptions are contained in a table.

| Image Title | Image Path |
| --- | --- |
| Red Tree | red.png |
| Green Tree | green.png |

In the report, I want generate a cell (for example a compose() in flextable) that would have the name of the image and the image inserted from the path underneath.

I then wish to tile that result such that the each row in the original table will be converted into  one of these cells and then paneled four to a page, as in the image below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnFt9.jpg)

I have hundreds of images to put into this report and would prefer to do it programatically, and then export it into a word file or similar editable format.

I have managed to build the cell using flextable but I do not know how to take that result and tile it onto a page.

I do not know where to being with the tiling. So far I have managed to create the cell and insert the image using compose(), but I do not know how to get the resulting body to present as in the image instead as in another row in the existing table.

Comment: I don't use it  often but normally for reporting with images rmarkdown would be the answer. It is dependent on strict file management. If you would like an answer on your question it is advised to always add (part) of a reproducible code. This way people can see what you tried and what you are stuck at.